# WCF String from service to client without asking

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service, client

Iam currently trying to make an WCF - WPF Apllication that will get a string.

Step-by-step visualisation:

1. Client and Serice starts
2. Service processes something
3. when something important is processed it will send a string to
   the client
4. The client will show this string on a label

...

Ok, i got it so far that i can communicate with service and client but i think thats not the real thing i want...
the client and the service starts and the client will call a function with this function the service is being called and it will display a message.box
thats working...but not the thing i really want...

Is there a good approache to let the service send a string to the client, without the client asking for it ??

Comment: You need to read about Duplex services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction ! Ill look this up, thanks :)

Comment: just to let you know...i just realised, i used this example to build my project : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/

is this what you were talking about when you meant duplex ?
because exactly this example is basically my project

Comment: what is the problem? your client call a function of the service just to subscribe itself to the future callbacks.  You can check more examples like this [WCF Chat Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: so you telling me, if i would now start a timer in my service, it would do , for example, sending a string to my client, so i dont need to call the main function again?

Comment: Sure, check the sample I have linked.